# window.onbeforeunload does not work when i choose to stay on the page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have an xhtml page for file Upload:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{ContentRepositoryExplorerBean.upload}" 
              update="formId" dragDropSupport="true" multiple="true"/>
```

and i need to make confirmation dialog for user when for example he press "sign out"
What i do is:

```
<script>
        var flag = false;

        function setFlag(v) {
            flag = v;
        }

        function getWarningMessage() {
            if(flag == true) {
                window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                    return 'Please do not leave this page until upload is done';
                }
            }
        }

        $('#logout').click(function() {
            getWarningMessage();
        });
</script>
```

and adding to fileUpload onstart and oncomplete

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{ContentRepositoryExplorerBean.upload}"
   update="formId" dragDropSupport="true" multiple="true"
   onstart="setFlag(true)" oncomplete="setFlag(false)"/>
```

but when i choose to stay on the page my upload is not showing in the list where it should be. Any ideas a appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "upload is not showing in the list where it should be" ?

Comment: i have a list of file i'm displaying. and after i upload a file it should appear in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this issue by change the script a bit:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        var flag = false;

        function setFlag(v) {
            flag = v;
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var onclickFunc = new Function($('#logout').attr('onclick'));
            $('#logout').on("click", function(event){
                if(flag == true) {
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    alert("Please do not leave this page until upload is done");
                }
            }).click(onclickFunc).removeAttr('onclick');

        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display dialog while upload is in process.

***Create dialog (outside of your main form):***

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false"  header="Loading please wait.........."
            closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
            <p:outputLabel value="Uploading file..."></p:outputLabel>
        </p:dialog>
```

change your p:fileUpload as

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{ContentRepositoryExplorerBean.upload}"
   update="formId" dragDropSupport="true" multiple="true"
  onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();" 
  oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide();"/>
```

Now if user does upload then it will show a popup with text message.

Comment: Thank you. But this is not quiet i'm looking to achive. While File upload i need to have possibility to surf and show confirm dialog only when user is trying to logout or close browser, or close the tab.

Comment: Best of luck with your requirement. Where have you seen such thing ?

Comment: my customer want so))